# launch ros node over built-in wifi of arduino yun mini

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to link my Arduino yun mini with a built-in wifi with my PC (on Ubuntu 14.04, ROS Indigo) over wifi and run the ROS-node on the Arduino with the following command :

rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py tcp

or

rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=tcp _baud:=57600

But when I launch that,
[INFO] [WallTime: 1475872810.849287] ROS Serial Python Node
Fork_server is:  False
[INFO] [WallTime: 1475872810.858924] Waiting for socket connections on port 11411
waiting for socket connection

I don't understand that error because when I link them using USB connection with network port selected as my access, I don't have any problem. I searched on Google but nothing solved this problem.

Thank you !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245253/launch-ros-node-over-built-in-wifi-of-arduino-yun-mini/) by [suraj-reddy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28170/suraj-reddy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to @ahendrix, I managed to adapt its code for ESP8266 to connect as Ros serial client over WiFi. I supose you can adapt it to Arduino Yum, by creating the class WiFiHardware, that will create the method necesary to connect with:
$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py tcp

Please find a working demo code for ESP8266 (not Yum)  at https://github.com/agnunez/espros  that you will probably adapt with Yum includes, instead.
Have fun,
Agustin

---

Originally posted by [anunez](https://answers.ros.org/users/29929/anunez/) with karma: 16 on 2017-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0